# Перенос текста при уменьшении экрана

Tags: css, html5

подскажите как решить проблему. Есть что-то похожее на меню с текстом внутри контейнеров. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать так, что бы при изменении размеров экрана текст не пропадал(как сейчас), а переносился на новую строку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Код

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 92%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("../img/menu-background-image2.jpg");
}
.menu{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.left-item{
    background-image: url("../img/info.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.center-item{
    background-image: url("../img/structure-background-image2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.right-item{
    background-image: url("../img/simulator-background-image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fon{
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100px;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fon:hover{
    line-height: 350px;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Меню </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/CSSForMenuPage.css" TYPE="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu left-item" >
        <a href="TheoreticalInformation.html"> <div class="fon" > Теоретическое введение </div> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu center-item">
        <a href="Structure.html"><div class="fon"> Структура установки </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu right-item">
        <a href="Simulator.html"> <div class="fon"> Симулятор установки </div> </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: убрать line-height

Comment: Вместо line-height: 400px —  `.fon { display:flex; align-items: center; }`

Comment: спасибо большое, заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите line-height, пример реализации:

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    height: 92%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url("../img/menu-background-image2.jpg");
}
.menu{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
.left-item{
    background-image: url("../img/info.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.center-item{
    background-image: url("../img/structure-background-image2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.right-item{
    background-image: url("../img/simulator-background-image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fon{
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100px;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fon:hover{
  transition:all 1s linear;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Меню </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/CSSForMenuPage.css" TYPE="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu left-item" >
        <a href="TheoreticalInformation.html"> <div class="fon" > Теоретическое введение </div> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu center-item">
        <a href="Structure.html"><div class="fon"> Структура установки </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu right-item">
        <a href="Simulator.html"> <div class="fon"> Симулятор установки </div> </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало